# mvc3 Object reference not set to an instance of an object, cant figure this out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object-reference

I am getting an error of **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** I have tried multiple things but keep getting that error, the error is occuring on this line of code

```
  @if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.profile.photo))
    {

  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.profile.firstname)  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.profile.lastname)
  }
  else {

    <p>This user does not have a profile</p>
  }
```

**@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.profile.photo))**

I have a view that contains 2 models as

```
public class relist_profile
{
    public relisting relisting { get; set; }
    public profile profile { get; set; }

}
```

and my controller is

```
public ActionResult detail(int id)
    {
        relisting relistings = db.relistings.Find(id);
        var profiles = (from s in db.profiles where s.registrationID == relistings.RegistrationID select s).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(new relist_profile {profile = profiles, relisting = relistings });
    }
```

what is occuring is that when the **var profiles** doesn't match up **(s.registrationID != relistings.RegistrationID)**  then it throws the error but if there is a PROFILE and it matches(TRUE) then everything works perfectly.
How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Probably `Model.profile` == null??? That is `profiles` in `detail(int id)` is null

Comment: The FirstOrDefault will allow for the first matching value or null and If you use the result from this call in subsequent cals you will need to check it for null before doing anything. If you Called First() then the exception would be raised in that statement as it is valid for a single result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is no match by `registrationID`, [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) returns `null`. So `profiles` in `public ActionResult detail(int id)` is null then and `null` is consequently passed into the view.

You cannot access `Model.profile.photo`, when `Model.profile` is null. Try to add null check:

```
@if(Model.profile != null && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.profile.photo))
{
    //... 
}
else {
   <p>This user does not have a profile</p>
}
```